# What's inside the file hashes.txt.sig?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, source, update

I studied the monero-gui code and in the file `monero-gui/src/qt/updater.cpp` I found two addresses to verify binaries:

- https://web.getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt
- https://web.getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt.sig

The first file (hashes.txt) is in text format and it is clear to me that hashes and a digital signature are written there.

The second file (hashes.txt.sig) is in binary format. I have a question: what is this file and what utilities is it generated by?

Answer (score 2):

> what is this file...

`hashes.txt.sig` is a detached signature (from one of the projects maintainers) for the contents of `hashes.txt`.

> and what utilities is it generated by?

GPG. E.g. `gpg -b hashes.txt`.

Comment: However, further these two files are checked so that they are signed by different persons.

`throw std::runtime_error("both signatures were generated by the same person");` 

How exactly does the process of signing a distribution package work?

Comment: See this [QA](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12304/security-model-for-new-auto-update-feature-in-gui-v0-16-0-2-nitrogen-nebula).